# How to make popup modal inner element div resize when changing screens/window hight is changed?

Tags: html, css

I have popup modal that appears like this in two different screens:

[image]

[image]

The fist picture represents how I want things to appear. The second pictures happens when I change the height of my browser window.
Here is the code and the css for this popup:

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <div class="modal-content animated fadeIn">
        <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div id="header" class="headerClass"></div>
        <div id="myDiv" class="added">

        </div>
        <div id="buttons" class="buttonsClass"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto; /* Full width */
height: auto; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
}
.modal {
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
margin-bottom:auto;

}
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {

background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
height: 75%;
}
  #myDiv {
width: 90%;
overflow-x: auto;
display: flex;
position: relative;
margin-top: 100px;

padding: 15px;
 }
```

#myDiv is the div where those three rectangles are represented.
How can I avoid this from happening?
When window is snmaller I want the popup to stay with the same hight and then just add a scroolbar.

Comment: you modal seems to change size, you should maybe add a % for margin-top: 100px; as current the margin would be pusing the three green rectangle down by 100px no matter the size.

Comment: I have something in my code to deal with this where I subscribe to window events through a service (angular code that is). There may be a way to subscribe to window resize events and modify the position based on it, but that may be overkill

Comment: I think there is an easier way, but thenk you anyway. I'll try and sdo some research about it

Comment: @Simon, what do you mean by adding a % exactly?

Comment: I added an answer with a sample code.

Comment: Please use vh vw for measurements. It will help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your height is set to 75%, change that to auto if you want the .modal-content div to expand to fill the parent div, this will then add scroll bars as you want.

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you want the modal only to be 75% should be able to add the height to the parent container, currently, you have this set to auto, change it to a %.

Comment: When I added this, nothing changed

Comment: you want it to stay the same height? cuurently you have the .modal-content set to 75%?

Comment: you also have padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */ remove or change that to %

Comment: That helped. I just changed the height in.model-content to auto and it solved my issue. Thank you. Maybe you can edit your answer so I can mark it as the solution

Comment: I adjusted the answer and added some more detail.